# How to get bytes into the right order when they pass through different platforms?

Tags: ios, c, byte-order-mark, mqtt

I'm developing an app which pass bytes through the network, the server declares its bytes order is Big-Endian. In my app, I wrap my data with a header which takes 2 bytes, I assign the byte as following :

```
int length = [self.dataLengthHeader length];
if (length <= 255) {
    high = 0;
    low = length;
}else if (length == 256)
{
    high = 1;
    low = 0;
}else {
    high = length/256;
    low = length%256;
}
Byte byte[] = {high, low};
NSLog(@"%hhu  %hhu", high, low);
NSMutableData *dataToSend = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:byte length:2];
```

For example[image: the first byte is 00, the second is 05]

The first byte is 00(8 bits), the second is 05(8 bits)

Where another app receives the header, it parse the header which takes 2 bytes into two int(two NSInteger would be better) to get the information of the real message.

```
NSData *twoBytes = [NSData dataWithBytes:payloadptr length:2];

NSData *low = [twoBytes subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, 1)];
int lowP;
[low getBytes:&lowP length:sizeof(lowP)];

NSData *high = [twoBytes subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
int highP;
[high getBytes:&highP length:sizeof(highP)];
```

Memory shortcut:[image: the first byte]

[image: the second byte]

When I log out the bytes, it turns out to be something like this:highP = 70074112  lowP = 365573
I can never get the correct result, anybody could help me?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why dont you base64 the data before you pass it through network? You could probably then attach the base'ed64 string to your header and do the the reversed operation on the client. But you would have to deal with strings which is much easier to debug

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question. Generally, when transferring data across a network, you use the library routines htons(), htonl(), etc. to put your data into network byte order. On the receiving end, you use ntohs(), ntohl(), etc. to put the data into the host machines byte-ordering. These functions decide whether the byte-ordering is different and either reverse the bytes or leave the data untouched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about [serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization).

You could make yourself using e.g. [htonl(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/htonl.3.html), or [endian(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/endian.3.html).

You could use [XDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Data_Representation) with [RPCGEN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpcgen), or [ASN.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASN.1).

You could use [libs11n](http://s11n.net/s11n/) (in C++). You could also consider [protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/), etc...

Unless you have a lot of data, or bandwidth, you may consider using textual serialization formats like [JSON](http://json.org/) (there are somehow flexible, easier to debug, etc...) or binary counterparts like [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/). Notice that sending data on a network is much slower than your CPU, so the overhead of textual serialization is generally lost in the noise (even if you compress it).